# Firebase Analytics JS SDK: unable to log event with "items" as parameter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to send the following demo data to Firebase Analytics.
I use the JS SDK for it.

```
firebase.analytics().logEvent('select_content', {
  content_type: 'image',
  content_id: 'P12453',
  items: [{ name: 'Kittens' }]
});
```

My Problem is that the "items" will be sent as [object Obejct] in the payload data.
I attached a screenshot.

It is documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.analytics.EventParams.html#items

Has somebody else already faced this problem, too?

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Everything else is being tracked correctly.